# Modules not loading all the time

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to split out a "prebid" file , so as I can have seperate files from the "bidders", analytics client, bidder settings and some other bits.  I've basically made my original file the main.js and have split out some of the code into different files such as

```
var pbjs = pbjs || {};
 pbjs.que = pbjs.que || [];
 pbjs.que.push(function() {
 pbjs.addAdUnits(adUnits);

requirejs(['bidder_settings']);     

requirejs(['pbjs_config']);

pbjs.requestBids({
 bidsBackHandler: initAdserver,
 timeout: PREBID_TIMEOUT
});
});
```

i'm trying to call in the files within the orginal file, so as it pulls those bits in,  it sometimes works but other times it doesnt seem to load certain bits, any clue what i'm doing wrong/ is there a way to make sure the file loads the "modules/ seperate file" in sequencence down the page?

Comment: What do you mean by "other times it doesn't seem to load certain bits"? Is it consistent in which ones fail and when they fail? Can you point to a specific function that might be causing the problem?

Comment: sometimes all the bidders load, as i can see them in a chrome extension, other times they don't load,  I cant actually tell whats going wrong though as there are no errors etc in google consule and no clue how to debug where its "breaking"

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an asynchronous race condition on your page where requirejs is not loading your modules by the time Prebid needs them to finish the auction. According to the [requirejs docs] (https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles) you should be using a callback to then run code that will require your loaded modules.

example:

```
var pbjs = pbjs || {};
pbjs.que = pbjs.que || [];

requirejs(['bidder_settings', 'pbjs_config', ],
    function (bidder_settings, pbjs_config) {
        pbjs.que.push(function () {
            pbjs.addAdUnits(adUnits);

            requirejs(['bidder_settings']);

            requirejs(['pbjs_config']);

            // do what you need with modules here

            pbjs.requestBids({
                bidsBackHandler: initAdserver, // make sure you utilize disableInitialLoad
                timeout: PREBID_TIMEOUT
            });
        });
    }
);
```